Django Project Redirecting to /accounts/login/ URL Despite Custom URLs Configuration
I’m working on a Django project and encountering an issue where the login functionality is redirecting to URLs like /accounts/login/ or /accounts/profile/ which I did not configure.
I have customized the login and registration views and removed the default Django authentication URLs. However, the server seems to be redirecting to these default paths.
Here are the details of the problem:
Project Setup:
Django version: 5.1
Custom views for login, registration, and logout are implemented.
The urls.py in my app does not include the default Django authentication URLs.
urls.py in the app (firstapp/urls.py):
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("index/", views.index, name="index"),
    path("error/", views.custom_404, name="error"),
    path("login/", views.login, name="login"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("profile/", views.profile, name="profile"),
    path("logout/", views.logout, name="logout"),
    # Remove or comment out the line below
    # path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# Remove or comment out handler404 if not using custom 404 view
# handler404 = views.custom_404


Views File (views.py):
python
@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "index.html", {"user": request.user})
    return redirect("login")


@login_required
def profile(request):
    customer = request.user.customer

    # Render the profile page with forms
    profile_form = CustomerUpdateForm(instance=customer)
    password_form = CustomerPasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

    return render(
        request,
        "profile.html",
        {"profile_form": profile_form, "password_form": password_form},
    )


@login_required
def update_profile(request):
    customer = request.user.customer

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomerUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your profile has been updated successfully.")
            return redirect("profile")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Please correct the error below.")

    return redirect("profile")


@login_required
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomerPasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Your password was successfully updated!")
            return redirect("profile")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Please correct the error below.")

    return redirect("profile")


def custom_404(request):
    return render(request, "error-404.html", status=404)


def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Username or Password is Invalid")
            return redirect("login")

    else:
        return render(request, "login.html")


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        name = request.POST["name"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        password_two = request.POST["password_two"]

        if password == password_two:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, "Email Already Exists")
                return redirect("register")
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, "Username Already Exists")
                return redirect("register")
            else:
                # Create User instance
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username=username, password=password, email=email
                )
                user.save()

                # Create associated Customer instance
                customer = Customer.objects.create(
                    user=user,
                    name=name,
                    username=username,
                    email=email,
                )
                customer.save()

                return redirect("login")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Password Not the Same")
            return redirect("register")
    else:
        return render(request, "register.html")


@login_required
def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return redirect("login")


Views code...
Issue Description:
Despite configuring custom URLs and removing the inclusion of Django's default authentication URLs, when attempting to log in, the application redirects to /accounts/login/ and /accounts/profile/, which results in a 404 error as shown in the screenshot enter image description here.
Question:
Why is my Django project redirecting to /accounts/login/ and /accounts/profile/ URLs, and how can I ensure it uses only the custom URLs I've defined? Are there any other settings or configurations I might be missing that could be causing this issue?
this is a screenshot of the error!
enter image description here
I tried to search for the problem, and I have searched on ChatGPT and Claude AI and I have tried to add the URL to my route, but it didn't work.

It would be helpful if you actually shared the view that makes these redirects.

You need to decorate your views using login_not_required
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_not_required 
@login_not_required
def public_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is a public view accessible without login.")

# Using Class Based Views
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


@method_decorator(login_not_required, name='dispatch')
class PublicView(TemplateView):
   ...

FOr more info read docs here
